# Setup In-App purchases for OS X app examples

Tags: xcode, macos, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I know there are references on Apple's Developer website, but I'm having a hard time successfully implementing the ability to have an in-app purchase into my Mac App.

I'm looking for something similar to MKStoreKit, IAPNoob, or IAPHelper.

There are many iOS classes that do most of the legwork, and are easy to implement within minutes. I'm hoping someone can point me in the direction of something like this for OS X apps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Implementing InApp Purchases for `iOS` and `OS X` are similar. You can use the same code for both. But for OS X you have to study about the [Validating Mac App Store Receipts](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/index.html) to validate the purchase at the launch of the application. You can refer the [RVNReceiptValidation](https://gist.github.com/sazameki/3026845) for the reference. It is easy to Implement. If you have any doubt regarding this let me know that.

Comment: -> I've made some progress! I'm now having a new (related) problem. Any thoughts?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136751/current-receipt-invalid-or-mismatched-ds-person-id-images-included

Comment: that question is closed now. do you still have that problem ? If yes what is that ?